# How to update the datetime difference between all of the rows of a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got the following table with some data in it:

```
CREATE TABLE schedules
(
    ID        INT PRIMARY KEY,
    StartTime DATETIMEOFFSET(4)
);

INSERT INTO schedules
VALUES (1, '2020-03-27 08:00:00.000 -05:00'),
       (2, '2020-03-27 09:00:00.000 -05:00'),
       (3, '2020-03-27 10:00:00.000 -05:00'),
       (4, '2020-03-27 11:00:00.000 -05:00');
```

Currently, the interval of start times is every one hour. I want to run a query to change this interval to every 45 minutes. I tried the following query but it didn't work.

```
UPDATE r2
SET StartTime = DATEADD(MINUTE, 45, r1.StartTime)
FROM schedules r1 JOIN schedules r2 ON r1.ID + 1 = r2.ID;
```

Comment: This seems like you should be repopulating the table, not updating it. Especially if it's more 4 rows (which I suspect it is).

Comment: @Larnu Yes, the actual data is like 10k rows.

Answer (score 1):

As I suggest in the comment, repopulating the table will be far easier here, especially if you have more than 4 rows in the actual table (which I suspect you do).

For this, i wou0ld use `TRUNCATE` and then repopulate with a Tally:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.schedules;
GO

DECLARE @StartTime datetimeoffset(4) = '2020-03-27 08:00:00.000 -05:00',
        @EndTime datetimeoffset(4) = '2020-03-27 11:00:00.000 -05:00';

WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT TOP ((DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @StartTime, @EndTime) /45) + 1)
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1 AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4, N N5), --100,000 rows
Dates AS(
    SELECT I+1 AS ID,
           DATEADD(MINUTE,I*45,@StartTime) AS StartTime
    FROM Tally T)
INSERT INTO dbo.schedules (ID, StartTime)
SELECT ID, StartTime
FROM Dates;
```

It's worth noting, as well, that this will create the new rows you need. If, for example, we use the example rows you have, chnaging to 45 minutes would mean there is no schedule at `2020-03-27 11:00:00.000 -05:00`. On the other hand, this method creates 5 rows, as there are 5 45 minute intervals between the two date times.

Answer (score 0):

You get the new times by simply numbering the rows in order to know how many fold you must subtract a quarter of an hour:

```
select
  id,
  dateadd(minute, starttime, -15 * (row_number(order by starttime) - 1))
from schedules s;
```

If you want your `schedules` table updated, that would mean to change all rows except for the first one. It is probably better to create a new table instead and replace the old one with it.

```
create table new_schedules as <above query>;
```

Then drop the `schedules` table and rename the `new_schedules` one to `schedules`.